# How To Change the Default Dropdown Pipeline in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure

When I run a pipeline in Azure DevOps, I notice that the dropdown defaults to the master branch. I want it to default to the develop branch. How do I change this?

Picture for context:

[image: Context Picture]

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can change the default branch in the 'Get Sources' section of the pipeline settings screen.

In long:

1. from the pipeline summary screen, press the *Edit* button to load the Edit screen
2. from the hamburger menu at top right, select *Triggers*; this loads the pipeline settings screen
3. in the settings screen, select the YAML tab over on the left
4. in the listing below, select 'Get sources'
5. in the edit pane to the right, there is a picker for 'Default branch for manual and scheduled builds', which will be ordinarily set to 'master' (or 'main'). Change this to 'develop' and save.

The next time you manually queue up a pipeline run, the branch picker will default to 'develop'; but note that this also affects scheduled pipeline runs too, so be careful if you have a schedule.